# How do I crop/resize a background/border out of an image with GraphicsMagick

Tags: resize, crop, edge-detection, graphicsmagick, picturefill

I have some images in a large set of images that have a white (or black) border that surrounds the image itself.  How can I...

1. Crop the image to a size without said background/border
2. Resize the image to fill a given output size centered.

For example, I have an uploaded image that is 1280x1024px in size, this has a white (or black) border where the interior size is say 800x700 (may not be centered), I want to crop out that border, then resize to fill a 640x480 output.  This will effectively take the interior image, then fill the 640x480 effectively cropping an additional 100px of height from the original.

---

I'd prefer something that can be a batch/shell script with graphics magick, but will accept a solution via phantomjs as well.  I'd prefer to avoid additional tools/languages if at all possible.

Comment: I've searched around a bit for a solution to this, and I can find the commands to crop, but not sure about actual detection... the fill I could figure out...  I should also be able to do this with phantomjs or something similar, but I'm hoping someone has a baked solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Trim](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) will remove borders according corners pixels,

[Extent](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent) and [Gravity](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravityhttp://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) will make the image a certain size and align it accordingly,

Also see [Geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) parameters,

```
convert -trim source.png trim.png
convert -extent 800x600 -gravity center trim.png frame.png
```

[image]

Here are the dimensions of the images shown :

- Source : 722 x 480
- Trim : 640 x 400
- Frame : 800x 600

**EDIT**

This will resize the image to fit 800 pixels wide, and make its height 600 if it is less:

[image]

```
convert -resize 800x600^ -extent 800x600 -gravity center trim.png resize.png
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#fill for all the details, particulary you should test how it behaves on portrait images.

Also, if you remove 800 at the `resize` parameter, it will fit by its height :

[image]

```
convert -resize x600^ -extent 800x600 -gravity center trim.png resize.png
```

**EDIT 2**

You must use the caret with one of the axes :

```
convert -resize 1200^ -extent 1200x600 -gravity center trim.png resize1.png
```

[image]

As you can see, top and bottom have been trimmed and the image is fitted according its width.

Comment: almost... lets say the final output is 300x180 (instead of a frame), I want the final output to take (trim.png) and have it scaled/centered in the output.png the full width will fit, but the top/bottom may be cropped out.

Comment: Or even if the final output is 800x600, I want the image scaled to "best-fit" centered vertically and horizontally.  Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: so if I do `convert -resize ^ -extent 800x600 -gravity center trim.png resize.png` that will resize to fill?  meaning if the aspect is different, it will cut off as appropriate?

Comment: See my other edit, is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: Close... basically I want it to crop to fit (if it's wider, by height, if it's taller by width)... I can only guess that using `^` without either param will do that... will give it a try later.

Comment: I'm thinking... `-geometry 800x600^ -crop 800x600 -gravity center` may well be what I need ... will try tomorrow. :-)